# Azure Synapse Current_TimeZone?

Tags: azure-synapse

How can I find the current timezone set for the Azure Synapse(SQL DWH). I have tried the CURRENT_TIMEZONE(), but it seems like Synapse doesnt support it. Any other feature available to find the same?

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: All Azure SQL DB and Azure Synapse SQL pools (DWs) are on UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timezone offset using the following:

```
SELECT DATEPART(tzoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

This returns an int value [ex: 0 for UTC], so you could use it in a CASE or subsequent lookup. It's not as direct as CURRENT_TIMEZONE() but should work.

Answer (score 0):

All Azure services use UTC time zone settings, regardless of their physical location.
Although you can change the time zone as per your requirement by creating a function to convert it.

```
Convert(DATETIME,@dateTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time')
```

[Source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fast-way-get-current-local-time-from-utc-synapse-stefan-quinn/?trk=public_profile_article_view)